# What the hell is Adobe Credential Management?

Tags: magento2, certification, adobe-commerce

I want to schedule my adobe certification exam but I found that my Legal name is not correct on https://www.certmetrics.com/adobe/candidate/demographics.aspx. Can anybody please help me if there is a way to fix this hell Or do I need to be reborn myself to fix this out?

[image]

Comment: You have to email them with legal proof and the name you want to change. they will change it

Comment: @RamkishanSuthar yes, they changed it by email with a legal proof.
Thanks